# Linux default file permissions

Tags: java, linux, debian, sudo, umask

I'm pretty much breaking my head over this one.
I'm running an exact ams Debian system as several other I am managing with the same kernel and same setup, however, the files being created by my java process running as a private user aren't getting the execute permission for the owner by default, which breaks the process.

The umask is 0022, so that's correct, I've tried setting up ACL's, but those seem to be getting ignored. The setup of the users itself also completely matches the setup on other machines where it does work.
It starts the java process trough sudo for the specific user. 
I'm pretty much at the end of what I can think of.

Comment: weird, check your sudoers maybe there is a mistake. Otherwise check the rights of mounted hard drive (in fstab) maybe execution is not allowed.

Comment: I've been working on this and found that if I start my monitor, which manages all these processes, manually, it works fine, but if I use the start-stop-daemon (trough /etc/init.d) it seems to be causing these problems.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some of the java code that creates one of these files? And indicate specifically what permissions the file is getting, and what you want it to get?